# Calling and displaying a WooCommerce custom checkout field value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I'm trying to display a custom field on an email.

Here's the script that I thought should work:

```
<?php if ($day) : ?>
<p><strong><?php _e('day:', 'woocommerce-pip'); ?></strong> <?php echo $order->day; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn't work. The name of the field is **`'day'`**.

Should this work? What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you saved the field to the database? Are you *sure* that it is there?

Comment: Yeah field is working perfectly in database. Your solution has worked perfectly, you are a champion, thanks!

Comment: @Adam You are welcome, It was not so easy to guess :)Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have already set correctly this custom field on checkout page with some code that displays the custom field and save the value of this custom field within the order in database *(if not, you will get nothing)*.

You need first to retrieve the `order ID` before trying to get the value of this custom field and there can be 2 cases:

1. You have already the `$order` variable or object. You  simply retrieve it with:

```php
$order_id = $order->id;

// or

$order_id = str_replace( '#', '', $order->get_order_number() );
```

2. You don't have the `$order` object, you  will need to get it first:

```php
global $woocommerce, $post;
$order = new WC_Order( $post->id );

// and after you can get the order ID

$order_id = $order->id;

// or

$order_id = str_replace( '#', '', $order->get_order_number() );
```

Now you can get the value and display it because you have `$order_id`:

```
<?php $day = get_post_meta( $order_id, 'day', true );
    if ( !empty( $day ) ) : ?>
    <p><strong><?php _e('day:', 'woocommerce-pip'); ?></strong> <?php echo $day; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But you should check in your database within the `order_id` as `post_id` in **`wp_postmeta`** table, that  a `meta_value => 'day'` exist with some value in the corresponding `meta_value` row/column. If not, there is certainly a problem with your code when you create this custom field and save the value on checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

For display custom field  like this

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), ‘tes_custom_field’, true ); ?>
```

for more information check this vary good tutorial  http://www.themelocation.com/how-to-display-custom-field-value-on-product-page-in-woocommerce/